# What’s the best way to find heart statues in terraria?

Tags: terraria-mobile

My terraria world is expert mode version 1.3.0.7(mobile), large.I have defeated all mechanical bosses other than Skeletron Prime. I have decided to set up 2 or even 3 heart statues if possible with timers during boss battle as part of my “heath station” strategy.

I just wanted to know if there’s anything I can do to increase my chances of finding heart statues in the underworld. I seem to find other statues more often than heart statues as I have found more than 10 bat statues and 3-4 mana statues, but I have found only one heart statue so far. I spent a couple of days finding them but no luck. Can anyone suggest some places in the map where I can look out for? What’s the odds of me finding 2 more in my world? Thanks
[image]

Update: Found 2 more heart statues after a very long search, so I have 3 heart statues totally and defeating Skeletron Prime was too easy with 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no specific spawn for heart statues. Your only way to find them is to search for areas where statues are more common.

Therefore I suggest that you look out for underground cabins (see https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Underground_Cabin). They are randomly generated structures in the underground and cavern layer and normally spawn with 1 or 2 statues inside.

To easier locate such cabins you could use a metal detector (dropped from a nymph) which will show you nearby chests, which also almost exclusively spawn in such cabins. You could also use the spelunker potion for easier finding of underground cabins.